# Synchronize single IMAP folder

Tags: c#, interop, outlook

I am trying to write an application that presents the user with a list of mail headers from a selected folder from shared IMAP folder tree. Users of the application use Outlook 2007 or 2010, and have the shared IMAP folder tree mapped to their account.

I am able to *access* a folder and iterate over the mail items using Outlook Interop like this:

```
Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook._NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.Folder folder = MyFolderFinder(...);

foreach (var item in folder.Items)
{
    if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
        // do something with mailItem
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this method does not appear to synchronize the folder, so unless the user does a manual "Update Folder" using Outlook, they may see a stale list.

Is there a way to programmatically synchrionize a single IMAP folder using Outlook Interop?

Comment: I'm no interop expert, but this behavior sounds right: you're asking outlook to give you mail items, so you get the items outlook knows about not the new ones he hasn't gotten yet. If the folder is on an Exchange 2007+ server you can leverage EWS (exchange web services) to go straight to the server itself (I wrote a small domain mail reader few days ago for self-training purposes, it's poorly documented but pretty straightforward in the end).

Answer (score 0):

Using the new mail receive event, I think you can do this.

```
private void ThisApplication_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.
        Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(
        ThisApplication_NewMail);
}

void ThisApplication_NewMail()
{
}
```

**Reference:** [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)